# Users Cannot Edit Onenote Notebook After Moving File

Tags: network-shares, file-permissions, microsoft-onenote

I have moved a Onenote notebook from one server to another. In the new location a user was able to open the notebook but not edit it. I checked the permissions and users only had Read and Open. I changed permissions to modify and had the user try again. Again they were unable to edit or add text to the notebook.

I created a new notebook in a share where the user had full control. Now they can edit it.

Do users need Full Control of the location of the OneNote files or for the OneNote files themselves to edit them?

Comment: Don't forget that the NTFS permissions are not the only permissions that apply here. If the used share has is read-only for the user you can add write permissions on NTFS level as often as you want - they will never be effective.

Comment: There may be more than one One Note file and folder in the basic directory where you see (in One Note) "one" notebook. So I give permission to the entire Folder

Comment: @Robert the NTFS section gives them READ/WRITE permission. The Share permission is Full Control. Yet users still cannot edit Onenote notebooks.

Comment: @John You give full permission to all the Onenote folders? Do you keep all the Onenote notebooks in one folder? Because if there is a onenote notebook in a share with a bunch of other files now all those files have Full Control for users.

Comment: Yes. One Note is using the main folder and then the contents within it.